# Async calls within setInterval where every next is dependent on previous

Tags: javascript, async-await, setinterval

I have a `setInterval` setup which internally calls an API. Based on the api response I manage `previousState` & `currentState` variables.

I need to make sure that every next setInterval stuff happens when the previous has updated by variables already.

How can I do it?

```
let previous = null;
let current = null;

const fakeApi = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve(1), 3000));
};

async function fetchData() {
  current = await fakeApi();
  callB(previous, current);
  previous = current;
}

function getStats(cb) {
  setInterval(fetchData, 3000);
}

function callB(prev, curr) {
  console.log(prev + " >>> " + curr);
}

getStats(callB);
```

Comment: Can you show us the current code?

Comment: I believe I spotted a mistake which every answer so far repeated. The first parameter of `setTimeout` has to be a function, but not only the OP, with immediately invoking `resolve` via  `resolve(1)` passes something entirely different to it. Thus, already `fakeApi` in my opinion should not work as expected, or even break.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I get your point, actually I missed it mistakenly, it's there in my original piece of code. Nice catch, btw!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setInterval, you could create an `sleep` function and then call the `fetchData` after its finished

```
let previous = null;
let current = null;

const fakeApi = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve(1), 3000));
};
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function fetchData() {
  current = await fakeApi();
  callB(previous, current);
  previous = current;
  await sleep(3000);
  return fetchData()
}


function callB(prev, curr) {
  console.log(prev + " >>> " + curr);
}

getStats(callB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a while loop to repeatedly call the api function:

```
let previous = null;
let current = null;

const fakeApi = async () => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
};


let getStats = async ()=>{
  while(true) {
      await fakeApi()
      callB(previous, current);
      previous = current;
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); //add delay between updates as required
  }
})()


function callB(prev, curr) {
  console.log(prev + " >>> " + curr);
}

getStats();
```